# What kind of SQL clause is this? Any way to convert it to SQL?

Tags: sql, propel

what kind of SQL is this?

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(prenotazione.VALUTAZIONE),0) AS somma, 
COUNT(*) AS numero 
FROM `prenotazione` 
WHERE prenotazione.USER_ID=18793 AND 
prenotazione.PRENOTAZIONE_STATO_ID IN (10,11)
```

I'm using propel as my ORM.

Any way to convert that kind of SQL to Mysql SQL?

Comment: As it looks (using backticks for quoting, `IFNULL`, etc.), this already *is* MySQL...

Comment: @user248959 - What exactly is the issue with the query?

Comment: @Beth MySQL supports Italian for table/column names since *at least* version 5.0.

Answer (score 2):

This query is valid in MySQL. It selects all rows from the `prenotazione` table where the `user_id` is 18793 and the `prenotazione_stato_id` is 10 or 11. The resulting rows are summarized: in the `numero` column you get the number of rows found, in the `somma` column you get the sum of the `valutazione` values. If no rows were selected, `SUM()` would return `NULL`. To prevent this, `IFNULL([expr1],[expr2])` is applied, which returns `[expr1]` if it is not null, and `[expr2]` if it is null. This makes sure you always return a number.

There is no easy way to do this with Propel, since your result cannot be easily mapped to a Propel object. The best thing you can do is use the underlying database layer (PDO) to escape your parameters and handle the resultset, and you don't open an extra database connection or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

When considering portability, Standard SQL is your friend. This query can be very easily transformed into Standard SQL-92:

1. Terminate the statement with a semi-colon.
2. Replace `IFNULL` with `COALESCE`.
3. Remove the single quotes from the table name.

With better spacing it could look like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(prenotazione.VALUTAZIONE), 0) AS somma, 
       COUNT(*) AS numero 
  FROM prenotazione
 WHERE prenotazione.USER_ID = 18793 
       AND prenotazione.PRENOTAZIONE_STATO_ID IN (10,11);
```

That said, for MySQL you probably would need to undo step 3... which leads me to suspect it was MySQL syntax in the first place.

Comment: AFAIK: The nice thing about `COALESCE` is, that it exists in Oracle, Mysql and Postgres, where IFNULL only exists in one or two.

Answer (score 0):

Using Babelfish to give a rough translation from Italian to English results in

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(reservation.APPRAISAL),0) AS sum,  
COUNT(*) AS number  
FROM `reservation`  
WHERE reservation.USER_ID=18793 AND  
reservation.RESERVATION_STATE_ID IN (10,11)
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Not... entirely sure how this answers the question. It's not like you could run this against the database for which the original query was written and expect it to work...

Comment: @djacobson: the intent is to help the individual understand what the query is doing.  The question appeared to center around the fact that the tables, columnns, etc in the database are named in Italian.  By providing a translation I hoped that @user248959 could focus on the query and not get messed up by the non-English names.